# SetTimeOut not working

Tags: magento2.2.2, jquery

I need to remove message after 2 sec but its not working

```
$.ajax({
                        'method': 'post',
                        'url': $form.attr('action'),
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'data': $form.serialize(),
    'success': function (res) {
                                if (res.success) {
                                    $form.find('[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
                                   var h = '<div class="message-success success message"><div>' + res.message + '</div></div>';
                                   $(h).insertBefore($form);
                                    $form.hide();
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        $(h).remove();

                                }, 2000);

                            } 
                        }});
```

Comment: Try console.log inside setTimeout function to check either it is coming inside it or not.

Comment: Yes.it is coming inside

Comment: Try assigning an id to your message div and then remove it by $("#id").remove();

Comment: This is something you should post in the general stackoverflow. It does not have anything to do with Magento 2 and you will get a quicker and more accurate response there. FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to try the code like this.

```
    $form.find('[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
    var h = '<div id="custommessage" class="message-success success message"><div>' + res.message + '</div></div>';
    $(h).insertBefore($form);
    $form.hide();
    setTimeout(function () {
         $('#custommessage').remove();
    }, 2000);
```